# Redshift/S3 - Copy the contents of a Redshift table to S3 as JSON?

Tags: json, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

It's straightforward to copy JSON data on S3 into a Redshift table using the standard Redshift `COPY` command.

However, I'm also looking for the inverse operation: to copy the data contained within an existing Redshift table to JSON that is stored in S3, so that a subsequent Redshift `COPY` command can recreate the Redshift table exactly as it was originally.

I know about the Redshift `UNLOAD` commnd, but it doesn't seem to offer any option to store the data in S3 directly in JSON format.

I know that I can write per-table utilities to parse and reformat the output of `UNLOAD` for each table, but I'm looking for a generic solution which allows me to do this Redshift-to-S3-JSON extract on any specified Redshift table.

I couldn't find any existing utilities that will do this. Did I miss something?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is to unload in CSV and write a simple lambda function that turns an input CSV into JSON taking the CSV header as keys and values of every row as values.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way to do this yet. So you might have to hack your query with some hardcoding :

https://sikandar89dubey.wordpress.com/2015/12/23/how-to-dump-data-from-redshift-to-json/

Comment: this is what he meant by per-table utility I guess, it's table-specific, and he was asking for a generic solution